# setting tax amount in Active Merchant / PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I need to know how to pass a tax amount to PayPal Express Checkout using Active Merchant and rails. Everything is working (completing transations) except I can't figure out for the life of me how to set the tax.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't you just add the tax to the amount to be paid with PayPal?

Comment: Thanks Edwin, but that didn't work. PayPal used to have an SDK for RoR that I've used before, and I was able to pass a tax amount that way. I just need to know how to do it through Active Merchant. There HAS to be a way, but I sure can't find it.

Answer (score 7):

This is how its done.

the following code will setup a paypal express purchase for 2 items that have different prices (5 and 10 $), plus added taxes (50 cents) and with no shipping or handling cost.

```
response = YOUR_PAYPAL_GAETWAY_NAME.setup_purchase(1550,
  :subtotal => 1500,
  :shipping => 0,
  :handling => 0,
  :tax => 50,
  :ip     => CLIENT_IP, # you might want to use "request.remote_ip" method from a controller to obtain this value

  :items => [
             {:name => 'ITEM_NAME_1', :description => 'ITEM_DESC_1', :amount => 500, :quantity => 1}, 
             {:name => 'ITEM_NAME_2', :description => 'ITEM_DESC_2', :amount => 1000, :quantity => 1}
            ],

  :return_url        => 'http://SOME/URL',
  :cancel_return_url => 'http://MAYBE/ANOTHER/URL'
)

redirect_to YOUR_PAYPAL_GAETWAY_NAME.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

NOTES:

- All amounts must be in cents
- All 4 options [:subtotal, :shipping, :handling, :tax] must be specified, if one or more is missing the rest will be ignored, if you dont need to set a certain option e.g. handling cost, just set it to zero like the example above, options set to zero won't appear on your paypal page.
- :subtotal must equal to the total items price in cent, i.e. (item1 * quantity of item1) + (item2 * quantity of item2) and so on...
- The total amount of the order (set to 1550 in the code), must equal to :subtotal + :shipping + :handling + :tax otherwise paypal will return an error (invalid transaction)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I left this project a long time ago so I won't be testing your solution against my code, but for the sake of posterity, I'm glad you posted. Thanks @Bash.

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders, if you add tax etc at setup_purchase function, you need to add that again at purchase function in order to look correctly at the Paypal page.

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed how old this is - but if for any reason anyone is looking for the answer, it looks like it's supported now if it wasn't before.

By the looks of things you need to have all 4 ':subtotal, :shipping, :handling, :tax' available and all must add up to the total amount you've passed through as your first option.